# iTunes Connect users Testflight broken?

Tags: app-store-connect, testflight

I am trying to invite testers to my iOS app through iTunes Connect, but when they receive an invitation, nothing is working..
Seen the screenshot below:
[image]

That is what happens when clicking the link from the iTunes Connect new user e-mail:

> Welcome to iTunes Connect. You have successfully created an iTunes
>   Connect account for 123@123.com. To complete the process,
>   activate your account using the password already associated with this
>   Apple ID.
>
> If you have any questions about this email, please use Contact Us.
>
> Regards, The iTunes Store team

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I just encountered the same issue.

Comment: Do you use Safari? iTunes Connect is compatible with Safari.

Comment: Yeah, I used Safari to open the activation url but didn't work.

Comment: Same here, Safari. Also tried Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/22323

Comment: There is a topic on Apple Developers forum for this issue.

Comment: I hope they fix this soon!

Answer (score 9):

The problem seems to be that a script in the page is referring to a non-public hostname idmsauth-stable.corp.apple.com. I was able to workaround this issue by manually modifying the script in Chrome Developer Tools and re-executing the code in the Developer Console.

1) Open the activation URL in Chrome

2) Open Chrome Developer Tools (Cmd-Alt-I on OS X, Ctrl-Shift-I on Windows)

3) Go to the Sources tab

4) Find main.js (itunesconnect.apple.com/itc/**static-resources**/main.js)

5) Modify line 20 to replace "idmsauth-stable.corp.apple.com" with "idmsa.apple.com"

6) Select the contents of the main.js file and copy to the clipboard

7) Paste into the console (you may need to tap the ">_" button to make it visible)

8) Press "Enter"

You should now see the expected iTunes Connect spinner appear and eventually you'll see a Terms and Conditions window.

Credit by apboyle from apple forums

Comment: This fixes the problem only for me, not for all test users I invited.. They have no idea how to do this.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. If you only have a few users it may be a viable solution for now. Basically it's just pasting in the code in the console and pressing enter.

Comment: It worked. +1. You deserve a medal for figuring this out. Apple has to go back to school. This has been working this way for a while. Very sloppy.

Comment: You, friend, are a gentleman and a scholar.  Best. Hack. Ever.  May the wind ever be at your back.

Comment: You can also use [Resource Override](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/resource-override/pkoacgokdfckfpndoffpifphamojphii) plugin for Chrome to replace the link.

Answer (score 0):

It seems Apple fixed the issue, I don't get the white screen anymore.

Comment: Same here. Seems to be fixed. Hopefully for everyone.

Comment: I am having this issue right now: http://imgur.com/6a8bN0y. It's been like this for at least 2 DAYS! Does anyone else experience this?